# Track a user Name who hit the Link

Tags: google-analytics

I made a website page. I want to track a user name who hit the link.
I used Google Analytic. How can be possible?

Can this be done? If so, any guidance would be most welcome.

Comment: which name you want?
Do you want to ask every user about their name before clicking the link?

Comment: Just note that this is off topic as it's not related to coding, but if you are going to be storing the user's name in your GA data, then that violates Google's terms of usage. You cannot store any data that can be used to identify an individual, so that includes name, email, address, etc.

Comment: I want to track a page which uploaded in google drive. That pages are privately shared. I want to track that user Name when they hit the link.